# How do I beat Robert de Sable in the cemetary?

Tags: assassins-creed

I'm at the point in Assassin's Creed where I try to assassinate Robert de Sable on the cemetary in Jerusalem, but he notices that I am among the crowd and ambushes me with his men. I am having a hard time with that fight, it is far harder than the previous fights I got into.

I am constantly attacked by archers while I'm busy defending myself against the templar knights. The melee enemies are also pretty tough, I often fail parrying or counter-attacking them even when getting the timing right.

Any tips on how to win this fight? How do I prevent the archers from killing me and what do I need to know to effectively fight the templar knights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while since I've played that fight, but I hope my memory serves me well enough for some tips ;)

Concentrate on the archers first. You can't block their shots and once they hit you you are open for attack, making them such a priority target, that you can easily justify getting hit a bit trying to get them. I forgot if you can climb up to them, if not use throwing knifes. One or two should be enough to kill one. If you have got one, you should be able to get something between you and the second one so he can't hit you.

When facing the melee fighters, never forget that putting yourself in a corner or near a wall will reduce the amount of enemies you have to fight. Also if you can break free, you can run in circles for a while, regnerating <strike>health</strike> synchronization.

The following youtube user chose a different path; he just ran away to a more favorable fighting spot:

Comment: I recall at least one of the archers being reachable by climbing, but it's probably faster/safer to just kill them with knives.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with most strategies and decided to just try to get lucky. I ran away a bit to lose some enemies and give the archers less chance to hit me and then equipped my hidden blade. I stayed near Robert, hoping he would attack and I could counter-attack and kill him.

After a few tries I got lucky and managed to kill him, with most other guards still alive.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to fight the Templars while the archers are shooting at you. It is better try to run on rooftops (as told by the informer, not to fight all of them at once) to a more favourable place - if you are fast enough you will be able to face them one by one. It is a bit easier to kill them on roofs by just making them defend and backing them up to the edge of the roof, making them fall off.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier do the free the citizens being harassed by guards quests first near by the assassination point.  Run immediately to where your vigilantes will help out holding the knights while you fight.  This keeps you out of the way of archers and minimizes the amount of guards you face at once.  Even better if the grab your assassination target, use your quick blade for instant end to the battle

Answer (score 0):

What I did was ran from the court yard around the nearby corner there should be some vigilanties there (if you saved the citizen) they will help you by grabbing him. I waited til they grabbed him and then used my hidden blade.